# applying a mathematical operation to an entire dataframe in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame df that looks like this:

```
HMM         A     C     D     E     F     G     H     I     K     L     M                                                                     
M 1      9999  9999  9999  9999  9999  9999  9999  9999  9999  9999     0   
N 2      9999  9999  9999  9999  9999  9999  9999  9999  9999  9999  9999   
K 3      9999  9999  9999  9999  9999  9999  9999  9999     0  9999  9999   
K 4      9999  9999  9999  9999  9999  9999  9999  9999     0  9999  9999   
S 5      9999  9999  9999  9999  9999  9999  9999  9999  9999  9999  9999
```

I want to get apply a function `(2**(-x/1000))`  on all the elements of the dataframe so the 9999 becomes close to zero and 0 becomes 1.

I tried this:

```
prob=lambda x:2**(-x/1000)
df.apply(prob)
```

However, it returns an error:

```
("bad operand type for unary -: 'str'", 'occurred at index A')
```

Comment: it returns the following error:
"cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>", 'occurred at index A'

Comment: provide a [mcve], 
How do you build the dataframe?

Comment: @kdba: it means you have `str` at `index A`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `set_index` to move that str column in the index then use `apply`:

```
df.set_index('HMM').apply(prob)
```

Output:

```
            A         C         D         E         F         G         H  \
HMM                                                                         
M 1  0.000977  0.000977  0.000977  0.000977  0.000977  0.000977  0.000977   
N 2  0.000977  0.000977  0.000977  0.000977  0.000977  0.000977  0.000977   
K 3  0.000977  0.000977  0.000977  0.000977  0.000977  0.000977  0.000977   
K 4  0.000977  0.000977  0.000977  0.000977  0.000977  0.000977  0.000977   
S 5  0.000977  0.000977  0.000977  0.000977  0.000977  0.000977  0.000977   

            I         K         L         M  
HMM                                          
M 1  0.000977  0.000977  0.000977  1.000000  
N 2  0.000977  0.000977  0.000977  0.000977  
K 3  0.000977  1.000000  0.000977  0.000977  
K 4  0.000977  1.000000  0.000977  0.000977  
S 5  0.000977  0.000977  0.000977  0.000977
```